# How can I set api endpoint url in external file in angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, endpoint

I have an ordinary problem, when I build my angular project in development mode and copy dist files into server folder, when changed server url I can't find endpoint url to change it and I have to rebuild my project with new endpoint url.

How can I define endpoint of webapi's in external file to be dynamically in the future, for typically I store it in `environment.prod.ts` like bellow

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    serverBaseUrl: 'http://example.com'
};
```

and call in service files with command `this.http.get(environment.serverBaseUrl + '/api/...')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, but not the right way I think.

a)
If you are using containers and mircroservice, it's a good idea to have relative urls like '../api-service/login'.
If this api has not the same root, you can set up a proxy or load balancer.

b)
Another way is to set a placeholder serverbaseUrl: 'xxxxxx',  The deploy-script can replace xxxxxx in the compiled min.js files. I don't like this way, but it works fine.

c) It's possible to put a json config file in the asset folder   assets/config/urls.json.
This can be load at startup (app component). 
These urls can be set to each service via static forRoot(). forRoot must be implemented by you.
AppComponent constructor:

```
authAjaxService.forRoot(theJsonResponse);
```

and

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthAjaxService {

private static readonly config = {
    loginUrl: 'assets/mock-data/auth/login.json',
    logoutUrl: 'assets/mock-data/auth/logout.json',
};

static forRoot(config) {
    Object.assign(this.config, config);
}

login(loginData: LoginRequestData): Observable<LoginResponseData> {
   const url = AuthAjaxService.config.loginUrl;
   return this.http.post<LoginResponseData>(url, loginData);
}
...
```

c) will make the startup of your app slower, because you need an ajax call to get the config.

Comment: thanks. for simply use can I use this structure `serverBaseUrl: 'assets/config/urls.json'` in environment file

Comment: No, this is not what you want.